# Longest Gap between bunch of dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of dates, and I want to find the maximum gap between 2 dates. How would we do it in excel?

May 6, 2015
May 9, 2015
May 14, 2015
May 17, 2015
May 21, 2015

For example, this should give the answer, May 14 - May 9 = 5 days is the longest gap

Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually the gap between may 14th and may 9th is 4.  Better example as to the gap would be looking at consecutives dates  May 11th and May 12, since they are right after one another there is no gap or 0.

Answer (score 1):

lets say your column is column A starting in A2 and it is sorted.  In B2 place the following and copy down.

```
=A2-A3-1
```

the -1 is there because if you have consecutive dates, the gap is really 0 not 1.

In C2 place the following

```
=Max(B2:B9)
```

where B9 is the last row

as an alternative you could do:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,A2:A6-A1:A5-1,if(A1="",2,1))
```

Depending on if your A1 is empty or contains string like "Date" you need to adjust whether you are looking for the largest 1 or the second largest 2.  If there is a string, it results in an error.  The second argument "6" tells aggregate to ignore errors.  In this case you want the largest number so 1.  If it is blank, the calculation check proceeds as if the empty cell is zero and you get a number in the 4K range which is not what you want unless you are looking at dates more than a decade apart.  With that limitation in mind we really want to be looking for the second largest number.

This alternative assumes row 6 is the last row and row 2 is the first row with a date.

Comment: `A1:5` is missing an `A`.  good use of the aggregate() I was just about to post the same with max.  Your math is backwards on it though, `=AGGREGATE(14,6,A2:A6-A1:A5,1)` and i believe you do not need the -1.  Also since the last one will be negative you grab the first.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the errors, I apparently cant read from one screen and type on the other.  I firmly believe that the -1 should be there as if you have consecutive days, the gap is 0 even though they are 1 day appart.  so the question is do you want to know days appart or gap between dates?

Comment: it shouldn't be.  5/2/2016 - 5/1/2016 is 1.

Comment: It is only 0 when the dates are the same.

Comment: See http://imgur.com/AKJq0s6.  You need the first not the second largest and not the -1

Comment: I agree with you if you are looking at the difference in days and not the gap.  There is no gap between 5/2/2016 and 5/1/2016 the days are consecutive.  there is no gap between Monday and Tuesday but there is a 1 day gap between Monday and Wednesday.  but I will admit Tueday is 1day from Monday and Wednesday is 2 days from Monday.  All in the interpretation of what is meant by gap.

Comment: I was assuming the dates started in the second row. when they do the largest is some number in the 4K range because your wind up comparing a date to an empty cell. so the next one down or second largest is the biggest gap.

Comment: But I think you and the OP are using "Gap" in different ways.  Because of the math the OP did by hand when he/she says "Gap" they mean the difference.  So the "Gap" would be `1` on consecutive days.  as to the 2nd vs the 1st you are correct.  But if the OP is using titles then it will need to be the first, because the first iteration will return an error. see http://imgur.com/4WxYHwn

Comment: Thanks for the corrections Scott,  aggregate is not my strongest excel function as you can see.  As such it not my go to option.  As for the -1 I pointed out the definition of gap in a comment under original question as well as explained why it was there in the answer so a person can edit it out if they see fit.  The nice thing is either way, it will still be the maximum.  Think we got it covered now. 8)

Comment: You did great.  The more you play with AGGREGATE() the more you will use it.  It is my go to formula for this site because it does not require Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: but it only forces the array type calc with certain formula choices and I have not figured all those out yet.  I tried doing it with MIN the other day and that was a definite no go.  The only reason I can see doing aggregate for min is to ignore errors

Comment: Any time you would use MIN(IF()) or MAX(IF()) I would use Aggregate.  You are correct only 14 and above allow disjointed arrays.  For example =MIN(IF(B12:B20="Y",A12:A20)) would translate to =AGGREGATE(15,6,A12:A20/(B12:B20="Y"),1)